# What dictionary provides gender association for each word?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-gender

As a nonnative English speaker, I often struggle to define gender in many words. Earth is a “she”, war is “he”, for example, but what gender a word “person” belongs to? Same about thousands of other words. I hear people using opposite gender identifiers for the same words, with “she” being a growing trend in the English-speaking world. 
In case with indeterminate gender, like a word “child”, what noun do I use, given sex is unknown. Is it “he” or “she”?
Example: “A child of your own is a blessing. He/She will give you joy every day.”

Is there a dictionary that includes gender associations? I checked Merriam-Webster and other main publishers, but could not find anything.

Comment: It's important to understand that, unlike a language such as Spanish, English words are not commonly "gendered".  There are a few conventions -- ships and aircraft are regularly referred to as "she", for instance -- but war is hardly ever personified, and how to refer to a child of unknown gender has confounded folks for centuries.

Comment: I'll add that referring to ships, etc as "she" is now somewhat archaic.  It was more common before the turn of the 20th century, and has faded ever since.  You can 100% get away with referring to all inanimate or abstract nouns as "it".

Comment: All the cars I've owned over the past 40 years I've named Gertrude.

Comment: @DanBron - try that in the Royal Navy and see how far it gets you.

Comment: @HotLicks - it’s a shame there’s no rule. I see it as a waste of time, when for example delivering a speech and trying to be gender-neutral: “A user can access his or her profile...”, “Baby can feel her or his surrounding from very early age...”. In situations where a living animate object needs to be described in general term, English is powerless, while it has no problem being ingenious in cases like “4ever”, “EZ” and “Krazy Killah”.

Comment: @SimonS - If you don't like to waste time, why do you hang out on EL&U?

Answer (score 4):

In English nouns have one of three genders - masculine, feminine or neuter. Things that are actually male are masculine gender (man, father, bull). Things that are actually female are feminine gender (girl, mother, vixen). Everything else is neuter (table, mountain, idea), and the neuter gender is often used for non-human males and females too. Some would add a fourth gender "common" which consists of things that have a gender but it is undetermined from the word (child, rabbit etc). Common nouns are either treated like neuter ("I see the rabbit. It is large.") or given special treatment if that would be considered insulting ("I see the child. He or she is large.")

There is therefore no need to specify the gender of a noun, and dictionaries do not do it. They are easily determined from the meaning of the word.

There are some conventions and idioms where some neuter words are spoken of with a masculine or feminine gender in some usages - ships are sometimes called "she" and the Earth may be called "she", but it is not universal and it is not part of grammar. It is more grammatically normal to say:

> I saw the Earth and it was good

as to say

> I saw the Earth and she was good.

Many would say the second is unnecessary anthropomorphising.

Comment: ***Bulls***, for example, aren't *always* "masculine". Plenty of written instances of [*the bull turned **its** head.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bull+turned+its+head%22) Personally, I think notwithstanding persistent literary / poetic usages, mainstream English "actively" works towards eliminating syntactic gender. Witness ***dog*** long ago becoming primarily a gender-neutral identifier, and more recently the same happening with ***actor***, for example.

Comment: I think you should emphasize that your use of 'gender' for English is not syntactic, but purely semantic. There is no grammatical use of gender in English (for syntactic agreement). And when one uses the term 'gender' with respect to words one is almost always referring to syntactic gender. So that first sentence of yours I take to be at the very least very misleading. That is nouns in English do not have gender -at all-.